# Implementing a Command Design Pattern with static methods C#

Tags: c#, design-patterns, static

I know how to implement a Command Design pattern as follows:

```
public abstract class Command
{
   public abstract void Execute(string someString);
}
```

Say I inherit this ,as an example:

```
public class ConnectionCommand : Command
{
   public override void Execute(string connectionString)
   {
      ...do some stuff here...;
   }
}
```

Problem is to use this ConnectionCommand I need to first instantiate an object, but the commands are context free, so I would prefer to not have to instantiate anything to run the ConnectionCommand's Execute method. (P.S. the ConnectionCommand.Execute() will be run from an event ,in a delegate).

How would I recreate this kind of design pattern but allowing the methods to be statically called?

Comment: What does "context-free" mean here?

Comment: They don't require specific instance information to execute. They are just called from any other class and they do something without needing to know anything about the class that's calling them. Much like a static method might be used.

Comment: It seems that you have a leaky abstraction here: your abstract class has a `string connectionString` parameter, which implies some sort of connection command already.

Comment: Not the actual code, just an example . Yeah I spotted that too late . :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Delegates are C#'s built-in implementation of the command pattern. Why re-invent the wheel; use delegates, which support static, pure functions automatically.

So you have an event system and those events invoke delegates. You need those delegates to have state though, without creating instances of some class. That's where closures come in to play. As an example:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public static CreateCommand(SomeType state, SomeEventHandler eventHandler)
    {
        eventHandler += (s, e) => MyDelegate(state, s, e);
    }

    private static void MyDelegate(SomeType state, object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // do something with state, when the event is fired.
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree with this, problem is some of the commands don't just have their Execute method, they sometimes have Property lists, private methods ,etc. I wanted a Command base class to allow any such Command to be Executed from an event and this would use that Command class to do a bunch of stuff. Silimar to what Justin Harvey said bellow.

Comment: Wouldn't this still require instantiating `ConnectionCommand` class?

Comment: Yes , yes it would :P. Which is precisely my problem .

Comment: @BradleyMorris, if you want an OO-based command pattern, then instances of the command objects have to be instantiated somewhere. If you are using events, then you are already using delegates, so why would you then want the GoF command pattern on top of that? I must have misunderstood your question as I'm now confused as to what you want to do.

Comment: Exactly! How can you have base and sub classes with static methods? You have gotta pick one. Or create a utility class with static methods.

Comment: Delegates don't allow me to use a self contained command with properties and other methods etc. Unless I make a static command class with an Execute method that I subscribe to the delegate , but the problem with this is that it's no longer able to inherit from my abstract Command class, this is all fine and dandy and I might change to this, but I want the command class around because not all of my commands are static and I also need to be able to add commands to a command List.

Comment: @BradleyMorris, "Delegates don't allow me to use a self contained command with properties and other methods etc". Not true, that's what closures are for. I'll update my answer now that I (think I) understand what you are after doing.

Comment: Not what I expected , but it seems it might do the job. Thanks for the help, apologies for the terrilble explanation, still getting used to communicating across stackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I've used a 'CommandProcessor' when I've used this pattern:

```
class CommandProcessor
{
    static void Execute(ICommand command)
    {
        command.Execute();
    }
}
```

It is then used as such:

```
CommandProcessor.Execute(new ConnectionCommand {PropertyX = 1, ProperyY = 2});
```

It works nicely as your processor can effectively employ a 'pipe and filter' pattern to add cross-cutting concerns.

It can be enhanced with generics and overloads for parameters/return values, etc.

Comment: That seems like it might help solve my problem. Except it still requires instantiation, but at least it will neaten up my current code.

Comment: It is neat. I use a generic version with Castle Windsor and let it handle my instantiation. You end-up with: `CommandProcessor.Execute<ConnectionCommand>();`

Comment: Both of these answers seem to be very good, I'll try out both and see which one better fits my code( can't just yet, bit busy ).

Answer (score 0):

http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2009/07/02/closures-and-the-command-pattern/

A link to some of Bob Nystrom's stuff.
Using closures:

```
static class Commands
{
    // create a command to move a piece
    public static Action MovePiece(Piece piece, int x, int y)
    {
        return () => piece.MoveTo(x, y);
    }
}

class Program
{
    public static Main(string[] args)
    {
        // ui or ai creates command
        var piece = new Piece();
        var command =  Commands.MovePiece(piece, 3, 4);

        // chess engine invokes it
        command();
    }
}
```

A very neat way to do the Command Design pattern in C# using closure and a Factory, similar to an answer above but without state information. Still I've added it for completeness. The Commands.MovePiece can then be subscribed to an appropriate event to get triggered.